# Why isn't my image displaying on my webpage?

Tags: linux, image, web, html

Hello I'm a beginner at web construction and html and was wondering if someone can help me out..
my image won't display on my webpage. The picture file resides in the images directory which is in the same folder as the index.html file.

This is the part of the code from the index.html file

```
<body>
<h1> Minimalism  </h1>
<img src="../images/pd.jpg" alt="Partisal disinvestment">

</body>
```

yet the image won't display? is the path right? I also even set permissions like chmod 755 on the image file but nothing..please help thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="images/pd.jpg" alt="Partisal disinvestment">
```

`../` means one directory up, but your `images` folder in the same directory as `index.html`. So you can do `src="./images/pd.jpg"` (one `.` stands for the current directory) or you can leave it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `../images/pd.jpg` will be relative to the path where `index.html` is being served from.

In other words, if `index.html` is being served out of `/a/long/path/index.html`, your reference of `../images/pd.jpg` would mean the file `pd.jpg` would have to be stored in `/a/long/images/pd.jpg`, for the image to load.

Answer (score 0):

check the case-sensitivity of the filename.
e.g pd.**jpg** vs pd.**JPG**